# Group by certain number of columns but exclude them in select clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I would like to create few summary statistics and implement control structure in my data through Postgresql. For which I am using group by. The problem is I would like to not display a column in "Select" clause but group by clause forces me to use that column as well

I already tried using the below code but unfortunately I don't wish to group by 'Valuenum'. However I would like to make use of that column to create a new column (within_range) as shown in query below. My actual data looks like as shown below. Please note that it's only a sample. The subject_ids might repeat with different hadm_ids

[image]

```
select subject_id,hadm_id,count(*) as "Total no of records",
         case 
             when valuenum between 80 and 110 then 1
             else 0
             end as "within_range"
         from labevents where itemid in ('50809','50931','51529') and 
hadm_id is not null 
         group by subject_id,hadm_id,within_range
         order by subject_id,hadm_id
```

I expect the output to be like each subject grouped by their hadm_id's and the count of records (total number of records, within range) under each patient and their respective hadm_ids

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not use alias name in group by you have to direct use that one in group by or you have to use subquery or cte

```
select subject_id,hadm_id,count(*) as "Total no of records",
         case 
             when valuenum between 80 and 110 then 1
             else 0
             end as "within_range"
         from labevents where itemid in ('50809','50931','51529') and 
hadm_id is not null 
         group by subject_id,hadm_id,case 
             when valuenum between 80 and 110 then 1
             else 0
             end
         order by subject_id,hadm_id
```

here is cte version of your code

```
with cte as
(
select subject_id,hadm_id,case 
                 when valuenum between 80 and 110 then 1
                 else 0
                 end as "within_range"
             from labevents where itemid in ('50809','50931','51529') and 
    hadm_id is not null 


) select subject_id,hadm_id,within_range,count(*) as cnt
  from cte group by subject_id,hadm_id,within_range
```